# Change text from dynamically created button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change to text from a button that is dynamically created by JS.
I know how to bind a click event on the button, but don't know how to change the text when the page is loaded.

The html code of the button (this is dynamically created by a wordpress plugin).

```
<a href="#" class="btn loadMoreBtn" id="loadMored">Load more</a>
```

jQuery code:

```
jQuery('#loadMored').text('Toon meer producten');
```

Comment: What kind of button is it? Does it use a ``<button>`` tag or a ``<input type="button">`` tag?

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. Also doesn't work when I paste this in the console screen.
.text() works in the console screen but not when my website loads.

Comment: @alex it's an <a> tag

Comment: The button is at the bottom of the product list: http://axces.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/nl/product/

Comment: @DennisPerremans I'm not sure I understand? Please add the code of your button in the question.

Comment: what is your script file name? or are you doing that inside script tag?

Comment: Check that element is created when running code

Comment: Its better to wrap those functions in `document.ready` event listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to load script after elements are rendered. In `document.ready` for example or in the bottom of your HTML code.

Comment: Will be better if you add a code snippet as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Your button isn't actually a button but an anchor. To change the text inside it you would do `$("#loadMored").html("Toon meer producten");`.

Comment: Your answer is looking for a `<loadMored>` tag. The author's version is correct for updating the text.

Comment: You should use `#loadMored`. But anyways that is not the actual reason because the issue is with referencing before the load of the DOM